# GAE: Update the content a web page automatically

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb, page-refresh

I'm developing a web app which is a kind of ecommerce. So I want to develop a kind of message board for every item that is on sale.
It would be something similar to that (http://netdna.webdesignerdepot.com/uploads7/building-a-threaded-comment-block-with-html5-and-css3/demo/), whit a section at the end for posting your own message (as Facebook, something similar to that: http://sportscommunity.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/fbcomments.jpg).
After the press of the button the page will be updated and your message will be shown.

The problem i'm facing is showing a message posted by another user meanwhile you're on the page.
When the page is loaded all the message related to the item are loaded too and showed automatically. Messages are stored into a NDB GAE database.

My question is: how can I update the content of the page when a new message (written by a user that's is not me, and related to the item's page i'm looking) is stored into the NDB GAE database?

Any suggestion?

I'm not looking for a chat, but something more similar to the comment section of a Facebook's post: not updated in real time, but in reasonable amount of time and automatically.

I hope I have explained my problem well

Comment: This isn't really an App Engine issue.  Your web page will either need to create a socket to the backend, or ping a certain URL periodically to get any updates.

Answer (score 0):

I would have recommended the [Channel API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/channel/), but I just discovered that it is being [deprecated](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/deprecations/channel).

Instead, Google is recommending their [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/).

With this or any other web channel, you will need to write some client-side code (probably in Javascript).